# Can I find the position of a given value in a Binary Search Tree better?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I need some help on how to find the (sorted) position of a given value in a Binary Search Tree better than I already did (if possible).

I have another method that searches for the i-th element of the tree and returns the node. So basically I solved the problem by searching through the tree until I find the given value or the node's data is bigger than the value I am searching for.

Our teacher gave us the algorithm on how to find the i-th element by knowing how many elements are there in that subtree. That is why I am wondering if my problem can be done in less steps?

Thanks in advance!

This is the not so optimal solution:

```
template <class T>
int BST<T>::Rang(const T& x) {

int meret = root->size;     //meret = size of the whole 
                            //tree
Node<T>* temp = i_th_Node_rec(1, root);
int i = 1;
while (temp && i <= meret && x != temp->data && x < temp->data) {
    ++i;
    temp = i_th_Node_rec(i, root);
}

return (i < meret) ? i : -1;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the assignment. What does "sorted position" mean? What does "i-th element of the tree" mean?

Comment: @Vladar Akos In C++ indices for all standard containers (that implement indices) start from 0.

Comment: @Vladar Akos This condition x != temp->data && x < temp->data has redundant operands.

Comment: You don't need a loop. You can deduce its position from the sizes of the subtrees.

Comment: @Quimby Sorted position means that if I were to put every element into a sorted array what position would it have in that array.

Comment: @Vladar Akos And using this function call temp = i_th_Node_rec(i, root); is inefficient. Also it is not clear how you are accessing either left or right node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very similar to how you locate the i:th node, but "in reverse".

- If the element is in the root, its position is the size of the left subtree.
- If the element is to the left, its position is the same as its position in that subtree.
- If the element is to the right, its position is its position in that subtree, plus the size of the root's left subtree, plus one.

Comment: I solved it iteratively right now but your solution sounds better. Thank you!